# How do I interpolate ejs for internationalization?

Tags: javascript, webpack, internationalization, ejs

I've inherited this codebase from a previous developer and have been tasked with adding internationalization.

I'm using i18next to handle the selection from a few different JSONs containing various translations. 
Ideally I would like to be able to call `i18next.t('home.meta-title')` etc.. in the ejs template. If that can't be achieved I would like to be able to pass an object with all the relevent strings to the template for interpolation.

At this time I can't figure out how to pass data to the templates. The project has a webpack config which is handling the linking of the ejs and js files and looks like :

`new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', 'templates', 'home.ejs'),
      inject: true,
      hash: true,
      test: 'TEST',
      excludeAssets: [
        /(availabilityView|availability|press|legal|visit|addons).(js|css)$/
      ],
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: false
      }
    }),`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I was just looking for this...